# adding a php date into a JS function not working when adding additional years

Tags: javascript, php

The following is working fine for PHP and JS ($end is echoed successfuly):

PHP code

```
$end = date('Y/m/d H:i:s');
```

JS code :

```
var acountDownDate = new Date("<?php echo $end; ?>").getTime();
```

I'm trying to add 2 years to the php code as follows :

```
$end = date('Y/m/d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 years'));
```

but the JS code is not working in this case. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works if you change format of the date

```
echo $end = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('+2 years'));
```

```js
var acountDownDate = new Date("2021-11-10 06:18:34");
console.log(acountDownDate)
```

Comment: Still not working. If I remove the additional strtotime('+2 years') , your code will work. The following is the content of $end : 2021-11-10 14:19:22

Comment: I get a result of date function from there - http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/94484b183648169265b964d536857a2e248eaf58 .And if you 'Run code snippet', you will see that it works